# PHP lightbox generator does not work because the lightbox is not loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, lightbox

I got a simple gallery generator script from google that scans a directory and should generate a gallery with a lightbox effect for every image. Except it doesn't work, I only see the name of the image and I can click on it, but there is no lightbox effect.

[This](http://www.fatbellyman.com/webstuff/lightbox_gallery/) is where I got the script:

I see the website is from 2008 so this script is probably extremely old, but it was the only simple one I could find.

After I added the [lightbox files](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) I started to add the php script.

This is the PHP script I include on my gallery page:

```
<?
/**
 * @package Lightbox Images Gallery Display
 * @author Gary Hollands 2009 - http://www.solriche.co.uk/
 * Partly plagiarised from SimpleView Gallery Deluxe v2.1 - http://www.chromasynthetic.com/
 * @version 1.0
 * @copyright GNU General Public License, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * @tutorial This function searches a directory for files with specified image extensions and outputs them as HTML links.
 * Thumbnail files can also detected and excluded from listing.
*/
    function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel){
        $image_dir = $dir_to_search;
        $dir_to_search = scandir($dir_to_search);
        $image_exts = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $excluded_filename = '_t';
            foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
            $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
            $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
            $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
            $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
                if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false){
echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."' data-lightbox='".$rel."'>
<img src='".$image_dir.$filename."_t.".$filetype."' alt='".$filename."' width='100' height='80' title=''/>
</a>"."\n";
                }
            }
    }
    ?>
```

After I include the script, I add the following line to my page where the gallery should be loaded:

```
<?
    lightbox_display('images/', 'lightbox[lightboxname]');
?>
```

Does anyone see if I am missing something?

This is the html output on the page (of one gallery item):

```
<a href="images/Chevron-001.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox[lightboxname]">
<img src="images/Chevron-001_t.jpg" alt="Chevron-001" title="" height="80" width="100">
</a>
```

Edit:

Also I should add that I edited the following line in the PHP script:

From

```
echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."' rel='".$rel."'>
```

To:

```
echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."' data-lightbox='".$rel."'>
```

Because in the documentation of lightbox it says the `data-lightbox` attribute needs to be added.

Comment: so what does the html you generated look like? you're doing a lot of string mangling/manipulation in there. are you sure the html that comes out of there is actually correct? And yes, that code is pretty ancient/bad. There's far better ways of figuring out a file's extension than by looking for `.` and doing substring extraction, e.g. http://php.net/path_info

Comment: I added the html output in my question.

Comment: you may want to try to manually write a file with one lightbox link, get that to work, and compare the result to what your loop is creating.

Comment: @Burki I'll do that and get back here if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Burki I added the following line `<a href="images/Chevron-001.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>`  This is a "hardcoded" version of a gallery item. But still it only shows the title of the image, and not the image itself. So this probably is something with jquery or the lightbox files not being loaded correctly. I don't know what I am doing wrong though, all files are included in a header.php file which is included on the gallery page.